# Adjective for advice

Tags: adjectives

In my native language, there is an adjective for "advice *given without much consideration*". To translate it literally in English it would be **"void advice"** or **"dry advice"**. Meaning, the person giving such advice, has not taken any pain understanding real difficulties and problems of the person seeking advice.

I like to know what is the appropriate word for that in English. Please help.

Comment: possibly off-the-cuff, facile, superficial.

Comment: "Worthless advice" is often used. Also "cheap advice". As Ambrose Bierce put it, advice is "the smallest common coin".

Comment: Cheap advice is good. It borrows from the idiom "Good advice is never cheap."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**perfunctory**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perfunctory?s=t

performed merely as a routine duty; hasty and superficial

It's a very useful word. A pithy word. Comes in handy in so many situations.

> "She asked him for help. After giving her some **perfunctory** advice, he headed for the row of taxis near the hotel's entrance."

Answer (score 1):

The word advice self-contains the meaning that it is an activity done in good intentions, as compared to a mere suggestion.

**advice**
ədˈvʌɪs/Submit
noun
1.
guidance or recommendations offered with regard to prudent action

synonyms:   guidance, advising, counselling, counsel, help, direction, instruction, information, enlightenment; recommendations, guidelines

Since the idea is to communicate that the 'Advice' was not well-meant, you may refrain from actually calling it an advice.

**'Offhand'** is an adjective that means with little or no preparation or forethought. The adjective offhand describes a remark or comment that is made without previous thought or preparation.

Another common word to consider is **Casual**

made or done without much thought or premeditation

"a casual remark"

synonyms:   offhand, random, impromptu, spontaneous, unpremeditated, unthinking, unstudied, unconsidered, parenthetical, passing

Another word '**Nonchalant**' is used to depict the attitude the person who is speaking has adopted towards a situation.
Nonchalant - Casually unconcerned or indifferent.